# What is the best way to parse an html string and extract the id of a tag? $() v. $.parseHTML v. $().filter v.?

Tags: jquery

1) `$(html_str)` works if there are no `<script>` tags:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $select = $('<select id="select1" name="select1"> \
    <option value="o1">hello</option> \
    <option value="o2">world</option> \
  </select>');


  var id = $select.attr("id");
  console.log(id);  //=> select1


});
```

But `$(html_str)` 'fails' when the html contains a leading `<script>` tag:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $select = $('<script>alert("hello");</script><select id="select1" name="select1"> \
    <option value="o1">hello</option> \
    <option value="o2">world</option> \
  </select>');

  var id = $select.attr("id");
  console.log(id);  //=> script


});
```

A close reading of the docs shows that that is the expected behavior: the docs for `jQuery()`, i.e. `$()`, say:

> Return a collection of matched elements

http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2

...and the docs for attr() say:

> Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

...and the `<script>` tag doesn't have an id.

2) The jQuery() docs also say:

> For explicit parsing of a string to HTML, use the `$.parseHTML()` method.

And the `$.parseHTML()` docs say:

> Parses a string into an array of DOM nodes.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

Because that is just a javascript array containing non jQuery objects, in order to use jQuery functions on the array, you have to convert the array to a jQuery object, which is something `$()` can do as well:

```
jQuery(elementArray)

elementArray
Type: Array
An array containing a set of DOM elements to wrap in a jQuery object.
```

In other words, you need to do something like this:

```
var js_dom_node_array = $.parseHTML(html_str);
var $jquery_obj = $(js_dom_node_array);
```

which boils down to this strange looking construct:

```
var $jquery_obj = $($.parseHTML(html_str));
```

So let's give it a whirl:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $jquery_obj = $($.parseHTML('<select id="select1" name="select1"> \
    <option value="o1">hello</option> \
    <option value="o2">world</option> \
  </select>'));

  var id = $jquery_obj.attr("id")
  console.log(id); //=> select1

});
```

That works.  Now with a leading `<script>` tag:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $jquery_obj = $($.parseHTML('<script>alert("hello");</script> \
  <select id="select1" name="select1"> \
    <option value="o1">hello</option> \
    <option value="o2">world</option> \
  </select>'));

  var id = $jquery_obj.attr("id")
  console.log(id);  //=> undefined

});
```

That doesn't work. So `$($.parseHTML(html_str))` seems to work just like `$(html_str)`, but then there is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $jquery_obj = $($.parseHTML('<script>alert("hello");</script><select id="select1" name="select1"> \
    <option value="o1">hello</option> \
    <option value="o2">world</option> \
  </select>'));

  var id = $jquery_obj.attr("id")
  console.log(id);  //=> select1

});
```

Huh?  Why does that work?

And overlooking that one anomaly, why is `$.parseHTML(html_str)` even needed?  According to http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-htmlstring-versus-jquery-selectorstring:

> `jQuery(htmlString)` versus `jQuery(selectorString)`
>
> Prior to 1.9, a string would be considered to be an HTML string if it
>   had HTML tags anywhere within the string. This has the potential to
>   cause inadvertent execution of code and reject valid selector strings.
>   As of 1.9, a string is only considered to be HTML if it starts with a
>   less-than ("<") character. The Migrate plugin can be used to restore
>   the pre-1.9 behavior.
>
> If a string is known to be HTML but may start with arbitrary text that
>   is not an HTML tag, pass it to `jQuery.parseHTML()` which will return an
>   array of DOM nodes representing the markup. A jQuery collection can be
>   created from this, for example: `$($.parseHTML(htmlString))`. This would
>   be considered best practice when processing HTML templates for
>   example. Simple uses of literal strings such as
>   `$("<p>Testing</p>").appendTo("body")` are unaffected by this change.
>
> Bottom line: HTML strings passed to jQuery() that start with something
>   other than a less-than character will be interpreted as a selector.
>   Since the string usually cannot be interpreted as a selector, the most
>   likely result will be an "invalid selector syntax" error thrown by the
>   Sizzle selector engine. Use `jQuery.parseHTML()` to parse arbitrary
>   HTML.

3) `$(html_str).filter("select").attr("id")` works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $html = $('<script>alert("hello");</script><select id="select1" name="select1"> \
    <option value="o1">hello</option> \
    <option value="o2">world</option> \
  </select>');

  var id = $html.filter("select").attr("id");
  console.log(id); //=> select1

});
```

Comment: "And overlooking that one anomaly, why is $.parseHTML(html_str) even needed? According to http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-htmlstring-versus-jquery-selectorstring " -- isn't the explanation you've linked to and quoted more than enough already? You won't get a more detailed explanation than the one you've quoted.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that `.attr('id')` returns the value of the `id` attribute of the **first** element in the current jQuery collection.

> Huh? Why does that work?

Because [`$.parseHTML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/) strips `<script>` tags by default, and thus the `<select>` element becomes the first element in the jQuery collection. Quoting the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/):

> [...] `jQuery.parseHTML` does not run script in the parsed HTML unless `keepScripts` is explicitly `true`.

---

In the other hand, `$(htmlString)` keeps `<script>` tags, thus `.attr('id')` looks for a non-existent `id` attribute in the script element.

---

```
$(html_str).filter("select").attr("id")
```

This works because `$(html_str).filter("select")` returns a jQuery collection whose **first** (and only) element is the `select` element which you want to retrieve the `id` from.

---

And finally, the two `$.parseHTML` samples yield different results because of the whitespace between the tags, as commented by Wumpus.

In both samples, the script tags are stripped. One of the samples has whitespace between the script tag and the select tag, thus creating a text node:

```
console.log($.parseHTML('<script>alert("hello");<\/script> \
<select id="select1" name="select1"> \
<option value="o1">hello</option> \
<option value="o2">world</option> \
</select>')); // [textNode, select#select1]

console.log($.parseHTML('<script>alert("hello");<\/script><select id="select1" name="select1"> \
<option value="o1">hello</option> \
<option value="o2">world</option> \
</select>'));  // [select#select1]
```

Then these arrays are fed to `$()`, and trying to retrieve `.attr('id')` from a textNode fails silently returning `undefined`.

---

I believe you have figured out the rest in your question already.

---

### Which one is the best?

It really depends on your use cases. I'd personally keep using `$()` as long as it works, as the code looks cleaner. Of course, you can use `$.parseHTML` with `keepScripts` to provide some more future-proofness in case your HTML becomes more complex and may not start with a `<`.

Comment: **Because $.parseHTML strips `<script>` tags by default**  1) That is not my interpretation of the docs, and in fact when I `console.log()` the length of the array returned by $.parseHTML it is 2--not 1. 2) There are two examples of `<script>` tags in the html fed to `$.parseHTML` and they yield two different results.

Comment: @7stud 1) you can see that it actually strips the script tags in practice (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhhd7jeh/)), the docs could do with a bit more of detail. 2) Not sure if I understand, mind posting a fiddle? I'm pretty sure it'd be related to parseHTML stripping the script tags and the order of the elements.

Comment: The difference between your 2 parseHTML examples is whitespace between the tags, which gets converted into a text node between the elements in the returned array. This text node is the first thing in the array after the script is removed, so `attr` looks there and finds no id.

Comment: I posted two examples for `$.parseHTML`--in one case the id is undefined, and in the other it is 'select1', and in one case the array returned array by $.parseHTML has length 2, and in the other it has length 1.

Comment: @7stud see Wumpus's comment, he found the last piece of the puzzle. `=]` I'll prepare a fiddle and update the answer.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley, et all: Okay, thanks for the explanations.  So then I will set the `$.parseHTML` keepScripts argument to `true` and then use filter(). That's the best method?

Comment: @7stud "best" really depends on the situation. If `$()` works, I'd keep using it as the code looks cleaner. Of course, you can use `$.parseHTML` with `keepScripts` to provide some more future-proofness in case your HTML becomes more complex.

Comment: Whoops, I mixed up two of my choices.  I'll stick with `$(html_str).filter`.  My html has script tags that I want to keep.

Comment: @7stud looks good to me. `=]` Anything else that hasn't been answered yet?